# Laravel 10, restarting the services I receive unexpected identifier "string" error

Tags: php, laravel

after updating my application to Laravel 10 I'm receiving this error where I restart it:

> 2023-09-14 13:08:01 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/html/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
> 2023-09-14 13:08:02 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/html/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
> 2023-09-14 13:08:04 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/html/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
> 2023-09-14 13:08:07 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/html/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
> 2023-09-14 15:22:54 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/html/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
> 2023-09-14 15:22:55 2023-09-14 13:22:55,485 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 12
> 2023-09-14 15:22:55 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/html/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
> 2023-09-14 15:22:55 2023-09-14 13:22:55,615 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)
> 2023-09-14 15:22:57 2023-09-14 13:22:57,625 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 13
> 2023-09-14 15:22:57 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/html/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
> 2023-09-14 15:22:57 2023-09-14 13:22:57,728 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)
> 2023-09-14 15:23:00 2023-09-14 13:23:00,733 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 14
> 2023-09-14 15:23:00 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/html/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
> 2023-09-14 15:23:00 2023-09-14 13:23:00,831 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)
> 2023-09-14 15:23:01 2023-09-14 13:23:01,832 INFO gave up: php entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

Any idea?

Until now I restarted my application using a Docker installation:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        container_name: server
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - pgsql
            - redis
    pgsql:
        container_name: db
        image: kartoza/postgis:13.0
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
        environment:
            PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-xxxxx}'
            POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-xxxxx}'
        volumes:
            - 'sailpgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${DB_DATABASE}", "-U", "${DB_USERNAME}"]
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        container_name: redis
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    pgadmin:
        container_name: pgadmin_container
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment:
          PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
          PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-xxxx}
          PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
        volumes:
          - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
        ports:
          - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
        networks:
          - sail
        restart: unless-stopped
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailpgsql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    pgadmin:
        driver: local
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using for both CLI and Web?

Comment: php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/8.2
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/8.2/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/8.2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/8.2/conf.d/error_log.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/8.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/8.2/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini

Comment: That would be the command line (CLI). What version is the Web using? You can add a file in your public folder with `<?php phpinfo();` and browse to it, to find out exactly. Make sure to remove that file when you're done!

Comment: At the moment, the error doesn't allow to restart the weabbplication.

Comment: Actually, never mind. `/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0` says it's PHP 8.0. Line 25 is `private readonly string $version;` and [readonly properties was introduced in PHP 8.1](https://www.php.net/releases/8.1/en.php). You'll need to change your PHP version.